# Compare two lists 2D and determine differences VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, arrays, visual-studio

I declare my 2D lists:

```
Dim _invoiceitems As New List(Of List(Of String))
Dim _dbitems As New List(Of List(Of String))
```

Each List is filled like this:

[image: 2D Lists Filled]

Example Code To fill:

```
_invoiceitems.Add(New List(Of String))
_invoiceitems(0).Add("Code #")
_invoiceitems(0).Add("Quantity")
```

Well, now i need a third list called (_changesitems) Note that this result with the differences:
be the result of subtraction of quantities if this is found (dbitems - invoiceitems).

[image]

How i can get this result?

Comment: why not use a Dictionary instead of 2D list?

Comment: Excuse my ignorance, but you can give some example based to my example?

Comment: @JohnNuñez: Dictionaries are a collection of key-value pairs. I believe *volody* was suggesting the use of an `IDictionary(Of String, IList(Of String))`. This will allow you to find your collection of "dbitems" by using the "invoiceitem" as a key, instead of having to index into your 2D list collection by a meaningless integer (e.g. `_invoiceItems("invoice1").Add("Quantity")` vs. `_invoiceItems(0).Add("Quantity")`). LINQ could be used to get an exclusion set that identifies the differences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code will generate the results you are looking for:

```
Private Function getChangesItems(ByVal invoiceItems As Dictionary(Of String, Integer), ByVal dbItems As Dictionary(Of String, Integer)) As Dictionary(Of String, Integer)
    Dim changesItems As Dictionary(Of String, Integer) = New Dictionary(Of String, Integer)()
    Dim allCodes As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)()
    allCodes.AddRange(invoiceItems.Keys)
    allCodes.AddRange(dbItems.Keys)
    For Each code As String In allCodes
        If Not changesItems.ContainsKey(code) Then
            Dim dbQuantity As Integer = 0
            Dim invoiceQuantity As Integer = 0
            If dbItems.ContainsKey(code) Then
                dbQuantity = dbItems(code)
            End If
            If invoiceItems.ContainsKey(code) Then
                invoiceQuantity = invoiceItems(code)
            End If
            Dim changeQuantity As Integer = dbQuantity - invoiceQuantity
            If changeQuantity <> 0 Then
                changesItems.Add(code, changeQuantity)
            End If
        End If
    Next
    Return changesItems
End Function
```

I used dictionaries instead of lists as was recommended by others.  As long as your data only contains a code and a value, the dictionary is a better fit.  If you have more columns, I would suggest creating a class that contains properties for each column and then make a list of that class type, rather than a simple 2D list of strings.  Doing so would be more type-safe and easier to read.

Comment: Actually I have no words to describe their help, Your algorithm is so useful  in the project which carried out sincerely grateful +UP